# call php class staic method with associative array as parameter in smarty template

Tags: php, smarty

i m trying to call a php class static method in smarty template

```
Utility::GetURL(FALSE,"admin/users/delete.php",array("user"=>Encryption::encode($user->id)));
```

but it gives me a fatal error with message  Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that. Smarty templates are part of the view of your app. There should be no logic. Just assign `Utility::GetURL(...)` to a Smarty variable in your PHP code before you render the template.